# "When integrating Spring Boot with React, the cookie session appears as undefined."

Tags: spring, spring-boot

```
package simple.todolist.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                .allowedHeaders("*")
                .allowedMethods("*")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

CORS configuration

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public Todo_users loginUsers(@RequestBody Map<String, String> credentials, HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response) {

    String userId = credentials.get("userId");
    String userPw = credentials.get("password");

    Todo_users loggedInUser = todoUserService.login(userId, userPw);

    if(loggedInUser != null) {
        String sessionId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        session.setAttribute("loggedInUser", loggedInUser);

        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("sessionId", sessionId);
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setMaxAge(86400);
        response.addCookie(cookie);

        return loggedInUser;
    } else {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        return null;
    }

}
```

REST API

```
const handleLogin = async () => {
    try {
        const userData = {
            userId: userId,
            userPw: userPw,
        };

        const response = await loginUser(userData, backUrl);

        if (response) {
            loginUserId(response.userId);
            console.log(response);

            setCookie('sessionId', response.sessionId, { path: '/' });

            queryClient.setQueryData('loginState', { isLoggedIn: true });

            setAuthenticated();

            navigate('/posts');
        } else {
            throw new Error('Failed to log in');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Login failed', error);
    }
};

export interface UserData {
    userId: string;
    userPw: string;
}

export const loginUser = async (userData: UserData, backUrl: string) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${backUrl}/users/login`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(userData),
        credentials: 'include',
    });

    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to log in');
    }

    const responseData = await response.json();
    return responseData;
};
```

I configured the backend with the above code and the frontend with the below code. In the Chrome network tab, the cookie session is received correctly. However, when checking in the Application tab, the cookie session appears as undefined. Due to this issue, when logging in successfully and refreshing the page, an error occurs.

I've tried using Google search, network inspection, and console outputs, but I couldn't resolve the issue.

"I hope to receive a valid cookie session value instead of 'undefined' through Google search, network inspection, and application verification.